# included template in Yield (master template) does not load data from menu controller rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I'm getting some trouble to load my menu in my master template page (first time rails).

In my master template I have:

```
<header class="headline">
<%= yield :nav %>
<div class="container">
```

my menu views:

```
<% content_for :nav do %>
<nav id="top">
<a class="logo" href="/">WebsiteName</a>
<ul>
<% @menu.each do |m| %>
<li>
<a class="navTop" href="<%= m.link %>"><%= m.linkName %></a>
</li>
<% end %>                   
</ul>
</nav>
<% end %>
```

menu controller:

```
class MenuController < ApplicationController
def index
@menu = Menu.order("order_by ASC").all
end
end
```

The page renders correctly, but the menu is blank. If I visit the url that corresponds to the menu, I can see the data.

My question: Am I going to the correct way? How do I call the menu controller in all requests to load the data in all pages?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Paste in your application controller on the top before_filter :menu, :only => [:index].

Comment: Content_for will be invoked when menu controller be call but not each time. and one time you can call one controller but if you want a specific controller or action that performs before requested action then you need to before filter them. try localhost:3000/menus. you can see your menu appears.

Comment: I think I'm confused how I'm asking: Is there any way to call a controller from a view? @SSR

Comment: Not to worry. why are you fetching menu from database? is there any special reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't call one controller from another or from a view. If you need some code (such as setting up this @menu data) called for all your controllers you would add

```
before_action :set_menu
def menu
  @menu = Menu.order("order_by asc")
end
```

To your application controller (the .all is redundant in rails 4.